# VB6 install error - Feature you are trying to use is not available

Tags: vb6, installation

After installing VB6, when I open the VB6 editor, it is showing the following message,

> The feature you are trying to use is on a CD ROM or removable disk that is not avaiable.

What is the issue here?

Comment: It sounds like you have an incomplete install (or incomplete installation package). You can try reinstalling, ensuring that all options are checked. If that doesn't work, get the full install by downloading it from MSDN. You do have an MSDN account, right? If not, you could try purchasing Visual Studio 6 (good luck finding it, though).

Comment: I tried doing a complete Installation, but i still get the errors.

Comment: A quick search on Google yielded two possibilities: 1. Login as the local admin for that computer (not a domain admin or non-admin) when installing and using VB, and 2. If you have MS Office installed, try repairing the Office installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing VB6 on a machine without .NET did not create this error.

Answer (score 1):

Normally MSI allows you to choose certain features to be installed, not installed or to be installed on first use. You might have some issues in the installation. Try reinstalling and choose the complete installation to be done to your hard disk.

Comment: I tried doing a complete Installation, but i still get the errors.